# Continuity of function and topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this exercice

$E=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with the topology $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\},E\},$ and the space $F=\{x,y,z,w\}$ with the topology $\theta=\{\emptyset.\{y\},\{y,z,w\},F\}$

I must study the continuity of $f,g: (E,\tau)\rightarrow (F,\theta)$ where $$f(a)=f(b)=y,f(c)=w, f(d)=z$$ and $$g(a)=g(b)=g(d)=y, g(c)=z$$
I found that both $f$ and $g$ are not continuous on $E,$ $f,g$ are not continuous a $d$

Is it right what i say ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks to me as if $f$ is continuous, for $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every $U$ in $\theta$. Your description of $F$, however, is missing "w".

Comment: but f is continuous or not ?

Comment: You tell me! Write down $f^{-1}(\emptyset), f^{-1}(\{y\}), f^{-1}(\{y, z, w\})$, and $f^{-1}(F)$ and see whether they are all elements of $\tau$.

Comment: i use this definition $\forall W\in \mathcal{V}_{f(a)}, \exists V\in \mathcal{V}_{a}, f(V)\subset W$ and i see that for $d$ we have $\mathcal{V}_d=\{E\}$ and here f(V) is not a subset of $\{y,z,w\}$ witch is a neighbohood of $f(d)$ you see ?

Comment: But in this case, $f(V_d) = f(E) = \{ f(a), f(b), f(c), f(d) \} = \{y, y, w, z \} = \{ y, z, w \}$, which *is* one of the neighborhoods of $f(d)$. (The condition doesn't say it has to be a *proper* subset!)

Comment: @JohnHughes $g$ is also continuous right ?

Comment: See Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous is for every open set $V \in F$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $E$. Equivalently, $f$ is continuous if for every $V \in \theta$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is in $\tau$. Note that
$$f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in E \mid f(x) \in V\}.$$

So, look at all $V \in \theta$. Is $f^{-1}(\varnothing)$ open in $\tau$? Well, $f^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing$, and $\varnothing \in \tau$, so this is fine. How about $f^{-1}(\{y\})$? 
$$f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{a,b\} \in \tau,$$
so this is fine, as well. Similarly, $f^{-1}(\{y, z, w\}) = \{a,b,c,d\} = E \in \tau$, and $f^{-1}(F) = E \in \tau$, so $f$ is continuous.

Now, just use the same reasoning to decide whether or not $g$ is continuous.

Comment: g is also continuous right ?

Comment: Well $\{y\} \in \theta$, and $g^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{a,b,d\} \not \in \tau$, so $g$ is not continuous.